# Installing Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 caused error loading VS2012 projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

Today I've faced this weird error. On my Windows 8 machine I installed Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 and restarted the machine. But after that when I tried opening Visual Studio 2012 projects (being developed in C++), it gave me error:

The operation could not be completed. No such interface supported

[image]

I did not get any resolution even after looking for it on net. And there is no way to uninstall the framework. I am badly stuck. Any help would be really appreciated.

**UPDATE**

When I clicked on `Edit <project name>.vcxproj` menu it displayed another error:

> The 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage' package did not load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file 'C:\Users\ATUL\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ActivityLog.xml'.

I examined the file. In the last it has got this entry:

> ```
> <entry>
> <record>479</record>
> <time>2016/01/26 08:24:28.125</time>
> <type>Error</type>
> <source>VisualStudio</source>
> <description>SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage]</description>
> <guid>{E269B994-EF71-4CE0-8BCD-581C217372E8}</guid>
> <hr>80131500</hr>
> <errorinfo>No exports were found that match the constraint:   ContractName    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentTypeRegistryService
> RequiredTypeIdentity  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentTypeRegistryService </errorinfo>
> </entry>
> ```

It is however still not making me any sense. If anyone knows or has came across this, please advice me. Thanks.

Comment: Meanwhile, I got the solution which I've posted as answer :-) Thanks.

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing your solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this by removing folder:

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache`

and then restarting Visual Studio 2012.

(I found this info [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800087/getting-error-microsoft-visualstudio-editor-implementation-editorpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly) which helped me)